# Conexão PHP usando phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Boa noite, estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade de criar um site e-commerce, mas não estou conseguindo fazer conexao com o meu BD, alguem pode me ajuda ?
Quando eu rodo fica falando que está com erro na linha 17, mas eu n consegui arrumar, obrigado ! ! ! !

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\Trabalho fabiano\login02.php on line 17                                                                               
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in 


C:\wamp64\www\Trabalho fabiano\login02.php on line 17

Comment: Acho que mysql_connect() está obsoleto faz um bom tempo, segundo manual do PHP é mysqli_connect() -> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Dependendo da versão do seu PHP mysql_connect() não funciona se não me engano ele foi removido apartir do PHP 7, sugiro que use PDO pois mysql e mysqli são vulneráveis a injeção sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá, primeiramente você precisa dar uma lida aqui em [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask;), evite colocar imagens com o código e sim colocar o código mesmo.

Agora vou exemplificar as conexões com o banco de dados.

**A classe PDO**:

```
<?php
    $dbname="nome do banco de dados";
    $dbuser="usuário do banco de dados";
    $dbpassword="senha de acesso ao banco de dados";

    try{
        $conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword); #1
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); #2
    }catch(PDOException $error){
        return '<h3>Erro de conexão:</h3><p>'.$error->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
?>
```

1 - As conexões são estabelecidas criando instâncias da classe base do PDO. Não importa qual driver você quer usar; você sempre usa o nome da classe PDO. O construtor aceita parâmetros para especificar a origem do banco de dados (conhecida como o DSN) e, opcionalmente, para o nome de usuário e a senha (se houver).

2 - Além de definir o código de erro, o PDO lançará uma PDOException e definirá suas propriedades para refletir o código de erro e as informações de erro.

> [Documentação completa da classe PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)
>
> ## Uso apenas a classe PDO para novos projetos, o uso de mysql foi descontinuado, por isso sugiro que comece a levar com conta aprender o PDO, pois vai facilitar a evolução dos sistemas que você criar, isso é uma opinião minha.

**A Classe mysqli**:

```
<?php
    $dbname="nome do banco de dados";
    $dbuser="usuário do banco de dados";
    $dbpassword="senha de acesso ao banco de dados";

    $conn=new mysqli('localhost',$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname); #1
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Erro na conexão ('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error()); #2
    }
    $conn->close(); #3
?>
```

1 - Abre a conexão com o banco de dados.

2 - A função [mysqli_connect_error](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php), irá retornar uma string representando o ultimo erro que aconteceu com a ultima chamada a função mysqli_connect(). Se não houve erro, esta função irá retornar uma string vazia.

3 - Fecha uma conexão aberta anteriormente com o banco de dados.

> [Documentação completa da Classe Mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)
>
> **A classe mysqli é uma melhoria do mysql**

**O obsoleto mysql**:

```
<?php
    $dbuser="usuário do banco de dados";
    $dbpassword="senha de acesso ao banco de dados";

    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost',$dbuser,$dbpassword); #1
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Erro na conexão: '.mysql_error()); #2
    }
    mysql_close(); #3
?>
```

1 - Abre uma conexão com o servidor MySQL.

2 - [mysql_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-error.php) retorna o texto da mensagem de erro da operação MySQL anterior.

3 - Fecha a conexão MySQL.

> [Documentação do obsoleto Mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php)
>
> ## Aviso, esta extensão está obsoleta desde o PHP 5.5.0 e foi removida no PHP 7.0.0!

Devo ressaltar que é sempre bom ler a documentação e as funções que serão usadas no projeto, buscando sempre a melhor forma, um código limpo e bem comentado para que facilite futuras manutenções, mesmo que seja por outras pessoas.

Respondendo sua pergunta diretamente `(!) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\Trabalho fabiano\login02.php on line 17 (!)` significa que na sua versão do `PHP` ela ja tenha sido descontinuada.

Comment: Quando o DB é MySQL, PDO é inferior ao MySQLi em todos os aspectos e o MySQLi não está sendo descontinuado. Infelizmente pelo grande destaque em informações erradas na resposta o -1 é inevitável, mas estou aberto a rever caso sejam ajustados os problemas.

Comment: Consegui avançar muito no trabalho ! ! ! Obrigadão mesmo, agora so falta a aparencia xD

Comment: @Bacco, sem duvidas foi um equivoco meu falar que mysqli estava sendo descontinuado, não prestei atenção durante a revisão. Claro que mysqli quando de trata de MySQL é superior, é específico para esse banco de dados, porém sempre indico o uso do PDO, e sempre uso o PDO. Muito obrigado pelo puxão de orelha! Comunidade cresce assim! <3

Comment: @Bado eu quem agradeço, e peço desculpas pelo pequeno equivoco a respeito do mysqli, no mais, qualquer dúvida sabe que pode contar com a gnt, vamos fazer sempre o melhor para ajudar.